Finding pid for python script B execution on a terminal using popen from python script A
I have a python script "A" that uses subprocess.Popen to launch a gnome-terminal and then executes a different python script "B" in there. I am stuck with retrieving the pid for that newly spawned gnome-terminal so that I can terminate it later on when I see fit. Launching the script in the separate terminal is necessary for the intention of the application.
This is how the Python script "B" is being executed from Python script "A":
process = subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "--", "bash", "-c", "python scriptB.py"])

This is my attempt to find the pid for the process, it's grandparent, parent, and its chidren:
print(process.pid)                                          # prints 5152
print(psutil.Process(process.pid).children(recursive=True)) # len is 0
parent = psutil.Process(process.pid).parent()         
print(parent)                                               # prints 5151
parent = psutil.Process(parent).parent()
print(parent)                                               # prints 4372

None of these pids actually point to the pid of my interest which is in this case 5158. Terminating pid 5152 does not kill the new gnome-terminal.
When I run ps ax, I get this:
5151 pts/0    S+     0:00 python scriptA.py
5152 pts/0    Z+     0:00 [gnome-terminal] <defunct>
5158 pts/1    Rs+    0:10 /anaconda3/envs/env1/bin/python3 scriptB.py
5164 pts/2    R+     0:00 ps ax

How can python script "A" find this pid (5158) the most proper way?
Update:
On the windows version, I am using:
process = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", f"start cmd /k python scriptB.py"])

and finding the pid on windows is as same as the linux version. But I have no luck there as well.

Perhaps I'm stating the obvious, but not launching it in a separate terminal would be more manageable, as well as less intrusive. Let the user figure out if they want to run it in a separate terminal.

Process 5152 in that listing has already exited; it's in a zombie state until the parent calls a wait family syscall to collect its exit status.

Launching the script in the separate terminal is necessary for the intention of the application.

It might be helpful  to run the command line utility ps with options that print a "tree".
